# How to make a celery task fail from within the task?

Tags: celery, celery-task

Under some conditions, I want to make a celery task fail from within that task. I tried the following:

```
from celery.task import task
from celery import states

@task()
def run_simulation():
    if some_condition:
        run_simulation.update_state(state=states.FAILURE)
        return False
```

However, the task still reports to have succeeded:

> Task sim.tasks.run_simulation[9235e3a7-c6d2-4219-bbc7-acf65c816e65]
>   succeeded in 1.17847704887s: False

It seems that the state can only be modified while the task is running and once it is completed - celery changes the state to whatever it deems is the outcome (refer to [this question](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/2841/django-celery-task-custom-states)). Is there any way, without failing the task by raising an exception, to make celery return that the task has failed?

Comment: Have you tried to raise an exception from inside your code?

Comment: @hymloth Raising an exception makes indeed the task fail, which includes sending me an email everytime that happens - something I would like to avoid. Sorry for being unclear, I have changed the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an [interesting reply](http://groups.google.com/group/celery-users/browse_thread/thread/4273e16336b4b852) on this question from Ask Solem, where he proposes an 'after_return' handler to solve the issue. This might be an interesting option for the future.

In the meantime I solved the issue by simply returning a string 'FAILURE' from the task when I want to make it fail and then checking for that as follows:

```
result = AsyncResult(task_id)
if result.state == 'FAILURE' or (result.state == 'SUCCESS' and result.get() == 'FAILURE'):
    # Failure processing task
```

Comment: you if condition could be written as `result.state in READY_STATES | EXCEPTION_STATES:` where `from  celery.states import READY_STATES, EXCEPTION_STATES, UNREADY_STATES`

Answer (score 42):

To mark a task as failed without raising an exception, update the task state to `FAILURE` and then raise an `Ignore` exception, because returning any value will record the task as successful, an example:

```py
from celery import Celery, states
from celery.exceptions import Ignore

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task(bind=True)
def run_simulation(self):
    if some_condition:
        # manually update the task state
        self.update_state(
            state = states.FAILURE,
            meta = 'REASON FOR FAILURE'
        )

        # ignore the task so no other state is recorded
        raise Ignore()
```

But the best way is to raise an exception from your task, you can create a custom exception to track these failures:

```py
class TaskFailure(Exception):
   pass
```

And raise this exception from your task:

```py
if some_condition:
    raise TaskFailure('Failure reason')
```

Comment: Note that this will _not_ trigger the task_failure signal, so any handlers you want to attach to those will not be fired, which imo is not good.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. When you `raise Ignore()`  Celery will change the task's state from `"FAILURE"` to `"IGNORE"`.

Additionally, the above code doesn't work because Celery will reject `meta` when `status="FAILURE"` if `meta` does not have required string-valued keys `"exc_type"` and `"exc_message"`.

Comment: @Malcolm Using Idan Mann solution and `raise Ignore()` still reported a `FAILURE` for me with regard to what is displayed in Flower and as evaluated in `task.state` on the sending system.

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to further expand on Pierre's answer as I've encountered some issues using the suggested solution.

To allow custom fields when updating a task's state to states.FAILURE, it is important to also mock some attributes that a FAILURE state would have (notice exc_type and exc_message)
While the solution will terminate the task, any attempt to query the state (For example - to fetch the 'REASON FOR FAILURE' value) will fail.

Below is a snippet for reference I took from:
https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/09/28/celery-task-states/

```py
@app.task(bind=True)
def task(self):
    try:
        raise ValueError('Some error')
    except Exception as ex:
        self.update_state(
            state=states.FAILURE,
            meta={
                'exc_type': type(ex).__name__,
                'exc_message': traceback.format_exc().split('\n'),
                'custom': '...'
            })
        raise Ignore()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had issues with the accepted answers:

1. Raising `Ignore()` or `Reject()` from within the task led to the task being correctly in `FAILURE` state, but when running a Celery workflow (think `chain`, `chord`, or `group`) containing this failing task would always result in the workflow hanging:

```py
workflow = chain(my_task.si([], *args, **kwargs), other_task.s(*args, **kwargs))
res = workflow()
results = res.get() # hangs as the workflow never enters the ready state
```

2. I wanted the rest of the workflow to still run even if one of the tasks failed (not propagate exceptions, or have global error handlers that are difficult to work with)

So I ended up always marking the task as success and doing my own error post-processing after the workflow ends (always successfully):

```py
import traceback

def my_task(prev, arg1, arg2, opts={}):
  results = []
  state = {
    'state': task_state,
    'meta': {
      'custom_attr': 'test',
      # task metadata as needed
    }
  }

  try:
    # task code goes here
    task_state = 'SUCCESS'
    task_exc = None

  except BaseException as exc:
    task_state = 'FAILURE'
    task_exc = exc

  finally:
    state['state'] = 'SUCCESS'
    if task_state == 'FAILURE':
      exc_str = ' '.join(traceback.format_exception(
        etype=type(task_exc),
        value=task_exc,
        tb=task_exc.__traceback__))
      state['meta']['error'] = exc_str

    # Update task state with final status
    self.update_state(**state)

    return results
```

This has the advantage of:

- Keeping all the needed exception data (traceback)
- Avoiding the weird Celery post-processing of task states:

  - when tasks fail Celery replaces the dict data by the exception instance, which prevents having a consistent way of accessing task metadata
  - updating the `FAILURE` state without raising `Ignore()` or `Reject()` always result in task state being `SUCCESS`...
- Make complex workflows way more resilient to failures.

This allows me to always process workflow results in the following way:

```py
info = res.get() # this is always a dict containing metadata
error = info.get('error')
results = info['results']
custom_attr = info['custom_attr']
```